# Node PassportJS authentication: req.isAuthenticated() doesn't stay set

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Short summary of the problem: I'm using a new version of express (4.9.0) on a Node.js website which has a few public pages and a few private pages, which I'm putting behind a Google OAuth2 login, using PassportJS.  When I request a page behind the sign-in, the user keeps being asked to sign-in; `req.isAuthenticated()` isn't "sticky".  I've seen some comments online that there are can be problems with cookie parser versions being incompatible, so that could be the issue here.

Here is my (rather long) app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var googleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());  
app.use(bodyParser());  
app.use(session({ secret: 'mysecret' }));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {  
  done(null, obj);
});


passport.use(new googleStrategy({
    clientID: clientId,
    clientSecret: secret,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback"
},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    process.nextTick(function () {
      return done(null, profile);
    });
    }
));   

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'] }),
  function(req, res){   

  });

app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log("successfully authenticated with google");
    res.redirect('/');
  });


app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/auth/google');
});

app.get('/privatepage', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {

    var dostuff = module.listThings(function(rows) {
        res.render('somepage.html', {
            title : "some page",
            data : rows
        });
    });
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log("in ensureAuth", req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log("session data", req.session);
    console.log("user data", req.user);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
}


var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})
```

After the first login, if I visit the /privatepage URL, I get re-directed through Google and land on the homepage again.  This is what's in the log from those console.log lines:

```
in ensureAuth false
session data { cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: {} }
user data undefined
```

I assume this is some session issue where it doesn't store the user's logged in state, but I'm a node newbie & am a little stuck on how to fix this. I'm running on a single computer, so it's not a multiple machines issue.  Any debugging suggestions, or ideas on the conflict causing the logged-in state not to be stored?

Comment: I have the same issue with SailsJS. If I use Postman to send request -- or just use regular views -- I login, make subsequent requests for data... No problem. If I login from my Ionic app (AJAX), make subsequent requests -- I'm unauthed. However, if I login using 2 different browser tabs in Postman AND my app, I have no problem making requests in the app. Weird.